# Limit clause not working on Amazon S3 file containing a json array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently using following query:

```
SELECT * FROM S3Object LIMIT 7
```

Json file on s3 contains data in following format:

```
[
    {
      "name": "soemthing1",
      "score": 100000,
      "company_id": 1290920,
    },
    {
      "name": "soemthing2",
      "score": 5000,
      "company_id": 1290920,
    },...
]
```

What I would like to do is fetch the name and company_id of **first** **7** items of the array. What would be the query for this as my query is returning  all the rows rather than only 7 rows as specified by limit.

Comment: When you say it's not working, what do you mean? Do you get an error? Or the result is not what you expect? Something else?

Comment: @MilanCermak am getting all the rows rather than only 7 rows as specified by limit. Also I am unable to select specific fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

`SELECT s.name, s.company_id FROM S3Object[*][*] AS s LIMIT 7`

It's a bit wicked, but the `FROM` clause "drills down" into the JSON object in the file, so it's SELECTing from the objects in the array and not the (top level) array itself. See the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html#s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-from) for more.

Comment: S3Object[*] [*] worked instead of S3Object[*]. Could you explain why is it so? I am confused.

Comment: Read the last bullet point in the Note section in the link above. The way I understand it is this: the `FROM S3Object` and `FROM S3Object[*]` are equivalent and this path just selects the root-level object in the file. In your case, the whole array. So you have to instruct S3 Select to drill down once more, *into* the array, selecting all the objects inside of it - those are the values on which to apply the LIMIT clause (or the WHERE and SELECT ones). Adding the second `[*]` does this. HTH